# How to show LegendText in AmCharts for all bar, pie charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, amcharts

I am using AmCharts in my project and I am trying to show the Legend Text in my every charts for clear visibility purpose but I unable to set, So far I tried this but it wont work everywhere.

```
"legend" : {
            "align" : "left",
            "marginRight" : 200,
            "autoMargins" : false
        },
```

Please find the attached image files for more clarifications.

Thanks [image: Bar chart][image: Gauge Chart]

Comment: check this example https://jsfiddle.net/30ov3ev8/

Comment: I already mentioned that I tried with my above codes but it wont work in all charts.

Answer (score 0):

You want the graph's labelText to equal [[value]] and the graph's labelPosition to equal "top" for the bar graph.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it could you please ex plane more about it.

Comment: So, for your amgraph, you set your labelText value to equal [[value]], for example, if you have a setup like var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();, then you would set graph.labelText = [[value]]; and graph.labelPosition = "top";

Comment: Could you also show your code for the donut graph? (the bottom one)

Comment: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/solid-gauge/ @Sufi iman please check this link and there is a edit button on the right top you will find the complete code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `chart.legend` field.

Here is a working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6cg5swxL/4/